# How to get wi-fi channels on Mac High Sierra

Tags: macos, macos-high-sierra

I would like to get channels from wi-fi around me on Mac High Sierra. I tried Wireless Diagnostics but I can see only this window
[image]

I was going through the steps and then I got only some files and folders saved to my mac.

Can somebody please help? Thank you.

Comment: Click the wifi icon at top-right of screen whilst pressing the Option key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run this command:

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport -s
```

**Sample Output**

[image]